# Drop subgroup of obs in dataframe if first observation of group is na

Tags: r, vectorization

In R I have a dataframe `df` of this form:

```
a  b  year month id
1  2  2012 01    1234758
1  1  2012 02    1234758

NA 5  2011 04    1234759
5  5  2011 05    1234759
5  5  2011 06    1234759

2  2  2001 11    1234760
NA NA 2001 11    1234760
```

Some of the a's and b's are NAs. I wish to subset the dataframe by id, have each subset ordered by year and month and then drop the whole subset/id if the first observation in order of time of either a or b is na.

For the example above, inteded result is:

```
a  b  year month id
1  2  2012 01    1234758
1  1  2012 02    1234758

2  2  2001 11    1234760
NA NA 2001 11    1234760
```

I did it the non vectorized way, which took forever to run, as follow:

```
df_summary <- as.data.frame(table(df$id),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df <- df[order(df$id,df$year,df$month),]
remove <- ""

j <- 1
l <- 0
for(i in 1:nrow(df_summary)){

    m <- df_summary$Var1[i]
    if( is.na(df$a[j]) | is.na(df$b[j]) ) {
        l <- l + 1
        remove[l] <- df_summary$id[i]
    }
    j <- j + m 
}

df <- df[!(df$id %in% remove),]
```

**What is a faster, vectorized way, to achieve the same result?**

What I tried, also to double-check my code:

```
dt <- setDT(df)
remove_vectorized <- dt[,list(remove_first_na=(is.na(a[1]) | is.na(b[1]))),by=id]
```

which suggests me to remove ALL observation, which is patently wrong.

Comment: If you are using `is.na`, why are the values are `x` instead of `NA`? Instead of making it clearer, you are adding confusion. Regarding your `data.table`ish attempt you could try `setDT(df)[, if(!is.na(a[1]) & !is.na(b[1])) .SD, by = id]`

Comment: You are right, fixed.

Comment: Or another option could be `indx <- na.omit(unique(setDT(df), by = "id"), by = c("a", "b")) ; df[indx, on = "id", nomatch = 0L]` or instead of a join, you could replace the last part with `df[id %in% indx$id]`

Comment: Yes, the first one you suggested works and the number rows matches the one I have produced using the loops. Yours runs in seconds though XD. What is the .SD ?

Comment: Thank you for this and for pointers on where I can learn more!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are few `data.table` possible approaches

First- fixing your attempt

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, if(!is.na(a[1L]) & !is.na(b[1L])) .SD, by = id]
#         id  a  b year month
# 1: 1234758  1  2 2012     1
# 2: 1234758  1  1 2012     2
# 3: 1234760  2  2 2001    11
# 4: 1234760 NA NA 2001    11
```

Or we can generalize this (on expense of speed probably)

```
setDT(df)[, if(Reduce(`&`, !is.na(.SD[1L, .(a, b)]))) .SD, by = id]
## OR maybe `setDT(df)[, if(Reduce(`&`, !sapply(.SD[1L, .(a, b)], is.na))) .SD , by = id]` 
## in order to avoid to matrix conversions)
#         id  a  b year month
# 1: 1234758  1  2 2012     1
# 2: 1234758  1  1 2012     2
# 3: 1234760  2  2 2001    11
# 4: 1234760 NA NA 2001    11
```

Another way is to combine `unique` and `na.omit` methods

```
indx <- na.omit(unique(setDT(df), by = "id"), by = c("a", "b"))
```

Then, a simple subset will do

```
df[id %in% indx$id]
#         id  a  b year month
# 1: 1234758  1  2 2012     1
# 2: 1234758  1  1 2012     2
# 3: 1234760  2  2 2001    11
# 4: 1234760 NA NA 2001    11
```

Or maybe a binary join?

```
df[indx[, .(id)], on = "id"]
#         id  a  b year month
# 1: 1234758  1  2 2012     1
# 2: 1234758  1  1 2012     2
# 3: 1234760  2  2 2001    11
# 4: 1234760 NA NA 2001    11
```

Or

```
indx <- na.omit(unique(setDT(df, key = "id")), by = c("a", "b"))
df[.(indx$id)]
#         id  a  b year month
# 1: 1234758  1  2 2012     1
# 2: 1234758  1  1 2012     2
# 3: 1234760  2  2 2001    11
# 4: 1234760 NA NA 2001    11
```

(The last two are mainly for illustration)

---

For more info regarding `data.table`, please visit [Getting Started](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started) on GH